# Elseif never executing in onCommand

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin that adds "variables" into commands. You use /set (variablename) (value) to set a value and then you can use any command with var:(varname) (For example you could do /set foo bar and then do "/say var:foo" and it would say "bar" in chat) **For some reason my**

```
else if(Arrays.toString(args).contains("var:")) {
```

**is either never executing or always returning false. Why is this, and how can I fix it?**

Main plugin class:

```
public class main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    List<String> vars = new ArrayList<String>();
     public void onEnable()
     {
       getLogger();
       getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
       Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Variables Enabled!");
     }

     public void onDisable()
     {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Variables Disabled!");
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command,
            String label, String[] args) {
            if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set")) {
                vars.add(args[0] + ":" + args[1]);
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Variable " + args[0] + " added with the value " + args[1]);
            }else if(Arrays.toString(args).contains("var:")) { //Line problem is on
                int size = args.length;
                   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                   {
                      if(args[i].contains("var:")) {
                          String[] parts = args[i].split(":");
                          for (String temp : vars) {
                              String[] varname = temp.split(":");
                              if(varname[1].equals(parts[1])) {
                                  args[i] = varname[2];
                              }
                          }
                      }
                   }

            }
        return super.onCommand(sender, command, label, args);
    }

     }
```

EDIT: The way I know it is a problem with my else if is that if I add
`sender.sendMessage("test");` right under the elseif I never get the message "test" even when I have var: in my args.

EDIT 2: I've figured out one part of it. For some reason whenever I do something like /say or /broadcast the onCommand doesn't get fired...

Comment: What's the value of Arrays.toString(args) at the start of your method ?

Comment: can you try switching the `Arrays.toString(...)...` with `Arrays.asList(args).contains("var:")`

Comment: @amitfarag I'm afraid `asList` won't work in this case because the argument value is only split on spaces and will therefore be of value "var:foo" in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is not with the `else if` but with the innermost `if`. You compare the variable name of your command (foo) with the previously stored value (bar). Try instead:

```
                          if(varname[0].equals(parts[1])) {
                              args[i] = varname[1];
                          }
```

Of course, it would be even better to use more appropriate collection types. For example `vars` might be a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer. It seems I was having a lua hangover :P (Lua indexes at 1) but along with that problem there is a problem with the else if. I will update my answer with why.

Comment: Then please try to log your `Arrays.toString(args)` before the `if`-statement as JFPicard suggested.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think that is the reason it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem! The problem is that onCommand only fires when taking commands from your plugin. I had to use a playercommandpreprocessevent for this.

Answer (score 0):

The onCommand() method won't enable you to filter all the command requests being sent by a player, it only lets you implement the commands you listed in your plugin.yml. I would instead use the PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent which does allow you to "catch" all the commands a player tries to execute before they are handled by a specific plugin and change the command as well as the subsequent arguments.

I would also use a HashMap instead of a List that will map the names and values of the String variables to each other. Here's some example code I tested that should work:

```
//Somewhere else
private HashMap<String, String> variableMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
    if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set")) {
        if (args.length == 2) { //With this approach, the first argument is the name, the second the value
            variableMap.put(args[0], args[1]);
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Variable " + args[0] + " now has value " + args[1] + ".");
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@EventHandler
public void onCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    String[] args = event.getMessage().split(" "); //Get the message and split it to get the arguments
    String newMessage = args[0]; //In this example I preserve the original command, so I'm not changing the first argument
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("var:")) { //If it starts with "var:", case insensitive...
            String[] parts = args[i].split(":");
            if (parts.length == 2 && variableMap.containsKey(parts[1])) { //If it has two parts, and the variable map contains the name of that variable
                newMessage += " " + variableMap.get(parts[1]); //Add the variable name and not the original argument
                continue;
            }
        }
        newMessage += " " + args[i]; //If the argument is not a variable or it is wrongly formatted, add the original argument to the combined string
    }
    event.setMessage(newMessage); //Set the new command message or contents
}
```